# find col and row names with max value in standard residuals table in r

Tags: r

I've got a table in r with standard residuals. How I can print a vector with column and row names with max value?

```
          negative   positive
  drug_1 -2.0663666  2.0663666
  drug_2  1.1561265 -1.1561265
  drug_3  0.6446097 -0.6446097
```

I'd like to get [1] "drug_1" "positive"
Thank's very much for the help!

Comment: Positive and negative both have the same max value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own function for the task:

```
where_max <- function(y) {
  where <- which(y == max(y), arr.ind = TRUE)
  c(row.names(y)[where[1]], colnames(y)[where[2]])
}
where_max(x)
[1] "drug_1"   "positive"
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(
  list(
    negative = c(-2.0663666, 1.1561265, 0.6446097), 
    positive = c(2.0663666, -1.1561265, -0.6446097)
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c("drug_1", "drug_2", "drug_3")
)
```